# DateTime Formula Field Null in Apex, Not Null in UI

Tags: soql, formula-field, null

I created three formula fields on a custom object.

1. Formula(Date) references parent objects
2. Formula(Time) references parent objects
3. Formula(DateTime) references formula field 1 & 2.

When I query for these fields using SOQL, field 1 & 2 return their value. Field 3 returns NULL. If I open up the record, there is a value in the field.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to fix it?

I have tried using [`Formula.recalculateFormulas()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm?search_text=limits). When I performed this on a list i received an 'Unexpected Exception'.

When I called `recalculateFormulas()` on a single Object in the list, the value was now a valid date time (not null)

See the following code snippet:

```
List<cust)obj__c> listCustomObj = [Select Id, Formula1__c, Formula3__c FROM cust_obj__c];
system.debug(listCustomObj[0].Formula3__c) //null
//List<FormulaRecalcResult> results = Formula.recalculateFormulas(listCustomObj); //throws unexpected exception
listCustomObj[0].recalculateFormulas();
System.debug(listCustomObj[0].Formula3__c) //correct value
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the initial query returning null instead of the calculated value?
2. Why does the recalculateFormulas() method fail when called on a list?
3. Any way you can recommend (without changing my formula fields) that I can solve this?

Comment: Is this possibly related to [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bvw)?

Comment: Negative Drew. I don't believe the issue i am experiencing correlates to the known issue you tagged.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the initial query returning null instead of the calculated value?

I remember a long time ago there was a bug where you had to query the fields that the formula was referencing in order for it to evaluate. Perhaps this a regression? I'd recommend contacting support to confirm. Also, try using the Query Editor in the Developer Console to see if the value shows up null there as well (it shouldn't).

---

> Why does the recalculateFormulas() method fail when called on a list?

It shouldn't *fail*, but it won't *help*, either.

> This method doesn’t recalculate cross-object formulas. If you call this method on objects that have both cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields, only the non-cross-object formula fields are recalculated. --[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)

Consider logging a bug report with support if you have an error code.

---

> Any way you can recommend (without changing my formula fields) that I can solve this?

It *should* work. I think your best choice is to contact support and try to get help.

Also, follow the [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008bvw) that Drew Kennedy linked in the comments (thanks, Drew!).

Comment: Same behavior is happening in query editor. It doesn't appear (after testing) as if you need to query the fields the formula is referencing either. Ill log a case with Salesforce, was just trying to avoid doing that :S. Always seems like more trouble than its worth.

Comment: in response to saying that 'it wont help either', the reason I want to use recalculateFormulas() is because after I call this method on a record, formula 3 evaluates correctly. I can then use this value in apex logic. I dont know the implications of calling this method iteratively on a list of records. I would be more comfortable calling it on the whole list (as salesforce guides you to)

Comment: @Z33dawg Each call consumes one SOQL query, as if you'd performed another query. You're absolutely right that you should only be calling this method on a list instead of one at a time.

Comment: apparently this method does not affect SOQL Limits (if all info is present on sObject) --> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Formula.htm?search_text=limits
I still believe that calling it on each record is definitely NOT the way to go

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

This happened to me as well with date-time fields... we will have to implicitly convert the field to string for debugging purposes..

System.debug(obj) usually converts objects to a string using built-in string conversion functions but there is no inbuilt function for date/time.

```
String.valueOf(obj.formula3)
```

should do the trick for you in debug...

could you please try... Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Casting to a String still returns Null though

Comment: That's new to me.. I will also be interested in knowing the root cause 